# someone please help figure how many hrs i can get out of the battery fully charged. as i have a very import 6hr. event that's coming soon.

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a set of LED xmas  lights at 110V 6-10watts. I need to use a battery thats 12v ,7amp hour along with a converter:  SNAN 300W Power Inverter DC 12V to AC 110V Car Inverter with Dual AC Outlet and 4.8A max Dual USB Charging Port by SNAN can someone please help figure how many hrs i can get out of the battery fully charged. as i have a very import event that's coming soon and it's going to last 6hrs. do i need a bigger battery with more AMP to get 6-7hrs?or can this one go at least 6hrs? i plan on going to Amazon to get battery & converter

12 Volt 7 Amp Hour Sealed Lead Acid Battery (12v7ah , 12v 7ah , 12 V 7 Ah) Replacement.

SNAN 300W Power Inverter DC 12V to AC 110V Car Inverter with Dual AC Outlet and 4.8A max Dual USB Charging Port by SNAN

Comment: Reduce your question's title. **We do not care the least for your event**, we want to help you with your technical problem. Structure your question a lot better. Things like "please help me" just distract from the content. Add more punctuation. The first letter of a sentence is written in capital, and form does leave an impression with potential answerers. The symbol for "Volt" is **always** a capital "V", and not sometimes 12v, 12V.

Comment: Hey it's not xmas for months yet, what's the hurry? Just buy two batteries if it's that important.

Comment: You i was just trying to give as much info/detail that would help get me the correct answer to my question within the allotted limits the site gives us to do such. I'm new to this website in general. I'll say your tone in your reply sucks and was a bit offensive and rude. if you didnt' know or want to answer the question based on the info I did give or gave you should have just moved on. However I wish you a Blessed day in life.

Answer (score 2):

No, it probably will not last 6 hours.

The problem is efficiency. The battery has a nominal capacity of 7 Ah × 12 V = 84 Wh. The load requires 10 W × 6 h = 60 Wh. However, the efficiency of that type of inverter is very poor, probably on the order of 30% to 50% at best. That means that you need something on the order of 60 Wh / 30% = 200 Wh at the input of the inverter, which would require a battery with 200 Wh / 12 V = 16.7 Ah minimum.

You would be much better off getting a string of lights that operates from 12 V directly, and eliminating the inverter altogether.

Comment: Thank you Thank you so much for breaking this info down. i've never used a battery like this or inverter before and was having a hard time trying to convert all this watt,volt, DC, AC jumbo language. this was such a Huge help and the light suggestion was great didn't know they made lights that could opperate on this type of battery alone without the inverter. Again Thank you I have alittle time left i'll look into another battery and those lights.